# Modelling agent behaviour, where single agent operates under two conditions simultaneously

Tags: netlogo

Any tips on how to model agent behaviour in an environment where two sets of rules apply simultaneously.

Specifically, what I am looking to simulate is a situation where an Agent operates under a specific set of rules, such as an employee-employer relationship, but at the same time, operates on perhaps different "informal" rules, such as an employee-employee relationship. Effectively there are two network structures in place, but the agent operates in both structures.

Any example models out there that I could take a look at?

Answer (score 2):

(This is a model design question, not programming, so it probably belongs on the NetLogo user group instead of here.)

My colleague and I wrote a book on modeling decisions that are tradeoffs between competing objectives, in ABMs. It's focus is on ecology but the concepts could be useful for you.

The basic idea is to come up with an objective function that includes both "sets of rules" as you call them. Perhaps something like maximizing your relations with fellow employees without getting fired by the employer. Then build very simple models of how decisions affect the mechanisms that drive co-worker relations, probability of getting fired, etc. It's not simple, but it's very powerful and flexible. You won't find a simple approach that's very general.

The fun part is trying different variations and comparing how they work.

https://press.princeton.edu/books/paperback/9780691195285/modeling-populations-of-adaptive-individuals

Comment: The decision as to which rule set to use could also be affected by ( or determined by ) something environmental, such as how many other agents near me are going one way or the other.   This could create an avalanche of polarization and the world breaking into two camps.

Answer (score 1):

The same result as a single combined objective function might be a physics type model where the result of any single set of rules is a vector of some strength pushing ("nudging"?) the agent in some direction. Then you could have as many sets of rules as you want, each contributing it's own vector of force, and the final result would be a resultant combined net force and subsequent Newtonian F=m*a or rearranging acceleration = ( vector sum of forces )/mass.

I'm trying to imagine how I respond when the expectations of different groups I belong to clash, and whether a linear sum vector model describes it. I recall in college when I couldn't resolve Catholic support for the Vietnam War and "Kill for Christ" was a tongue-in-cheek slogan. I think in that case the "forces" didn't cancel out -- they resulted in ABANDONING membership in one of the groups to reduce cognitive dissonance.  So, not a linear sum of zero in that case.

Another unstable human approach might be to keep going back and forth when two forces attempting to dominate behavior conflict -- first going with one a few steps then feeling guilty and going the other way a few steps. So which one dominates at any given step might depend on one's recent path and history and which one you "owed" something to. Or imagine being married to two people and trying to keep both of them happy. Maybe you partition space and Monday-Tuesday-Wednesday you keep one happy and Thursday-Friday-Saturday you keep the other happy and Sunday you go fishing.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I’m under-thinking this, but..I would encode both (all) sets of rules, and have the agent execute those rules as appropriate.

So, how to choose and execute rules?

Per social interaction:

1. Execute one behavior randomly based on which relationships are present
2. Choose one or more behaviors, as #1 and execute all of them in a specific order
3. As above, but execute behaviors in random order
4. For all possible behaviors, assign a probability based on whatever factors (number of role-members present, utility, consequence, etc l)  Choose and execute one behavior randomly based on that probability (roulettes-wheel selection)
5. Choose more than one… execute in fixed or random order
6. Proportionate to the value of a “social-competence” property, Select a number of possible behaviors as #4. Then randomly select one of those to execute.

Here’s a code-segment example of #6

```
;; list of possible reactions
;; these are variables or reporters that report
;; an anonymous command that executes the behavior
Let action-list (list
  boss-action
  employee-action
  coworker-action
  peer-action
)
;; measure social situation
;; list of values from reporters
;; these are reporters that return a value
;; based on, for example, how many of that type of 
;; relationship are present.
Let choice-list ( list
  ( probability-of-doing-boss-behavior )
  ( probability-of-employee-behavior )
  ( probability-of-coworker-behavior )
  ( probability-of-peers-behavior ) 
)
;; think about situation, choose possible actions,
;; as many times as social-competence allows.
;; roulette-wheel should return the index of the selected action
Let reaction-list (n-values social-competence 
[ -> roulette-wheel choice-list ] )
;; choose an action from those options
Let action-index one-of reaction-list
;; execute that action
Run item action-index action-list
```

Comment: Want to mention, that Wade's ideas about the humanity of reconciling membership in different  conflicting groups and how that affects behavior could definitely be encapsulated in the probability reporters and the actions--for example, an action for coworkers might take the number of bosses and the number of employees into account..